# cannot build boost process using bjam

Tags: boost

I have trouble compiling boost process library using bjam. I downloaded the newest [version](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/index.html) (0.5) and copied the headers and lib folders to boost main directory. Then I called bootstrap, and "bjam --with-process" but I get an error complaining that the library process is not found.

> bjam --with-process
>   error: wrong library name 'process' in the --with- option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is header-only. You don't need to build it - just `#include` the appropriate headers.

Comment: Hi so once I downloaded the boost-processs library, I just copy it to my boost directory and include it in my project? I thought I need to compile the library to create the binaries

Comment: @spchuang Yes, just copy it to the right location. Some boost libraries need to be built, but the vast majority are header-only, including this one. For some reason, `Process` doesn't mention this in the documentation, but it's not yet an official boost library, so I believe the docs will be fixed.